# Are we able to create our own playlists on Android using SpotifySDK?

Tags: spotify

Are we able to create our own playlists on Android using SpotifySDK and is it possible any free-users can shuffle it and premium users can play any song they want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we able to create our own playlists on Android using SpotifySDK

Yes, that's possible. You may want to read about [Spotify's Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/), and any [Android SDK client/wrapper like the one made by kaaes](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android).

> is it possible any free-users can shuffle it and premium users can
>   play any song they want

The playlist itself would be accessible to any Spotify user using the regular Spotify applications on iOS, Android, desktop, or web. However, since Spotify's Android SDK doesn't allow for free users to play tracks it would only be possible to play music from the playlist for premium users.